# Where in the theme file the </body> should be?

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress is missing the `</body>` and `</html>` tag, where in the theme, which file, that tag should be in?

I am using the [Otzi Lite](https://catchthemes.com/themes/otzi-lite/) wordpress theme.

This is the footer code (footer.php):

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Otzi Lite
 */

/**
 * otzi_lite_after_content hook
 *
 * @hooked otzi_lite_content_end - 10
 * @hooked otzi_lite_sidebar - 20
 *
 */
do_action( 'otzi_lite_after_content' );

/**
 * otzi_lite_footer hook
 *
 * @hooked otzi_lite_footer_content_start - 10
 * @hooked otzi_lite_site_info_start - 20
 * @hooked otzi_lite_footer_site_description - 30
 * @hooked otzi_lite_social_menu - 40
 * @hooked otzi_lite_footer_content - 50
 * @hooked otzi_lite_site_info_end - 60
 * @hooked otzi_lite_footer_content_end - 190
 * @hooked otzi_lite_page_end - 200
 *
 */
do_action( 'otzi_lite_footer' );

/**
 * otzi_lite_after hook
 *
 */
do_action( 'otzi_lite_after' );

/**
 * otzi_lite_after hook
 *
 * @hooked otzi_lite_scrollup - 10
 *
 */
wp_footer();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the theme but generally speaking the closing `</body>` tag is usually found in `footer.php` file.

Since your theme is missing the closing body and html tags, just add this at the end of the footer:

```
# rest of your codes
wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've shared the footer code in my question. Can you please take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much. that works and now I can see the tags!